# ICallbackEventHandler request every 1 second

Tags: asp.net, ajax, callback, icallbackeventhandler

I have code that fires an ICallbackEventHandler every 1000ms. When I run this code locally the data responds quick like every 1 second.

I then uploaded this on the server and sometimes the data responds 1 second and sometimes 3 seconds and then sometimes 6-7 seconds, why is this?

The bit of code that makes this recursive call every 1 second to the server is below:

```
function MessageServerResponse(param, context) {
    if (param.length > 0) {
        var splitParam = param.split("~");
        var id = splitParam[0];
        var data= splitParam[1];

        $('#' + id).prepend(data);
    }

    setTimeout("MessageServerRequest();", 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u r the only person who use server, the response would be always 1 second. and u cannot expect client to dedicately response your script

1 of my trick to make it faster

- if u use normal <form> postback put as less as u can in form. more html in form means more data transfer
- if u  use updatepanel just keep it small or make dedicate update panel to boost performance
- for jquery, i'd suggest $.ajax({cache:true})

Comment: Thankyou for replying and taking time to answe rmy question. I just wanted to also ask maybe it is my script file, the script file contains a lot of javascript. I havent really made much of the Javascript in a reusable manner yet as im still working on other things. Could it be that making the script file much more lighter and code reusable might speed up the response?

Comment: from my experience, mostly ViewState causing performance drop. Bigger ViewState cause more load in each transfer.

Comment: i dont really need viewstate on the page, if i enableviewstate to false could i give that a go?

Comment: (update code sample)its really hard to tell what cause performance drop. Have to try passing something simple, such as simple text. just to test network performance?